# O que é CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?

Tags: c#, .net, string, culture

Instalei o Resharper e nesse trecho `x.Id.ToString()` ele sugere alterar para `x.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

O que é `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` e por que dessa forma é melhor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acredito que [o Resharper só quer que você seja mais explícito](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Specify+a+culture+in+string+conversion+explicitly). Não cometer o erro de usar o *default* sem querer.

Ele indica que você quer tratar o dado de uma forma neutra, que o computador entender de uma forma **universal**. Isto é um contraponto a uma cultura específica que importa mais para os humanos entenderem o dado. Ela nunca é alterada. Culturas específicas podem ser alteradas por legislação ou outros fatores.

O ideal é trabalhar com a cultura invariante por toda aplicação a não ser no momento de fazer interação com usuário ou trocar informações com outros componentes que exijam uma cultura específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Apenas complementando, as configurações regionais de idioma interferem nas transformações de valores em diferentes tipos de dados, como double e string, adicionando vírgula ou ponto como separador decimal conforme as configurações regionais de idioma da máquina. Ao utilizar o InvariantCulture você informa ao runtime que deve ignorar as configurações regionais de idioma e trabalhar sempre com o formato universal entre idiomas.